# $\sum_{n} a_n$ and $\sum_n b_n$ converge $\Longrightarrow^{?} $ $\sum_n a_nb_n$ converge in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $\sum_n a_n$ and $\sum_n b_n$ are two convergent series of reals (or complex), does the point-wise product $\sum_n a_nb_n$ converge?

I came to this question while looking the Abel's test for product of two series. (Of course, the product in Abel's test is different from I considered.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. Consider $a_n=(-1)^n/\sqrt{n}=b_n$. Then $\sum_n a_n=\sum_n b_n$ converges by the alternating series test, but $\sum_na_nb_n=\sum_n\frac{1}{n}$ is the divergent harmonic series.

Answer (score 6):

If you require that $a_k,b_k\geqslant 0$; the claim is true by Cauchy Schwarz, that is, $$\left(\sum |a_kb_k|\right)^2\leqslant \sum a_k^2\sum b_k^2  $$

Comment: oh! that's nice! can you give a link to this fact?

Comment: If either of the sequences consists of positive terms, it suffices for the other sequence to be bounded, and this is easier to show than using Cauchy-Schwarz.